# Getting the element for a Dropdown Menu

Tags: javascript

want to build a Dropdown Menu. On "click" the submenu should be toggle "show-subnav".

This is my code:

```
<ul class="mainnav">
  <li>First<span class="toggle">+</span>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li>Subnav I</li>
      <li>Subnav II</li>
      <li>Subnav III</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Second<span class="toggle">+</span>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li>Subnav I</li>
      <li>Subnav II</li>
      <li>Subnav III</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Third</>
</ul>
```

and this is my JavaScript:

```
const toggle = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle");

toggle.forEach(plusButton => {
  plusButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // How could I get the child from the mainnav li 
    // to toggle a class like:
    subnavi.classList.toggle("show-subnav");
  });
});
```

I want to toggle a class to the specific submenu-ul. But always get only the first submenu-ul.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Node.parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) and [parentNode.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children), and you will be able to get your `<ul>`:

```
// Inside your forEach()
plusButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // Get parent <li> of plusButton
    let li = this.parentElement,

    // Get <li> children (so <ul> should be in it right?)
        liChildren = li.children;

    // Filters liChildren to get your <ul>
});
```

The keyword `this` will not reference the clicked `plusButton` if you use an arrowed function.

Comment: From the html, it should probably be `this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle(...)`

Comment: Oops yeah, I read too fast. I will correct my answer (and I forgot something else). **EDIT** No wait, `<ul>` is a child of `<li>`

Comment: perfect! I think both (this.parentElement & nextElementSibling) are working.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using `parentElement` and `querySelectorAll`:

```js
const toggle = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle");

toggle.forEach(plusButton => {
  plusButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    plusButton.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".subnav").forEach(subnavi => {
      console.log(subnavi);
     subnavi.classList.toggle("show-subnav");
 }); 
  });
 });
```

```html
<ul class="mainnav">
  <li>First<span class="toggle">+</span>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li>Subnav I</li>
      <li>Subnav II</li>
      <li>Subnav III</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Second<span class="toggle">+</span>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li>Subnav I</li>
      <li>Subnav II</li>
      <li>Subnav III</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```